# A "new" keyword in Node.js and one in Java do the same thing?

Tags: java, node.js, instance

When I was writing node.js app, I happened to see the code like below:

```
var Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;
const mutex = new Mutex();
const release = await mutex.acquire();
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    release();
}
```

In Java world, this kind of mutex implementation would be something like this:

```
private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);

try {
    mutex.acquire();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // exception handling code
} finally {
    mutex.release();
}
```

From these examples, can I assume that `new Mutex()` and `new Semaphore(1)` are both instantiating new instances on memory?

I want to know the exact lifecycle of an object that is created by this `new` keyword in Node.js world.

UPDATE:

Thank you for all the useful comments. I have one more question. In express app, I'm writing a code something like this:

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const co = require('co');
const models = require('models');
const Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;
const CharacterCounter = models.CharacterCounter;

const mutex = new Mutex();

router.get('/message', function (req, res, next) {
  co(function* () {
    const originalText = req.body.message;

    const release = yield mutex.acquire();
    let addedCount = 0;
    try {
      const { currentCount } = yield CharacterCounter.findOne(); // get total character count so far
      addedCount = currentCount + originalText.length;
      yield CharacterCounter.updateTotalCharacterCount(addedCount); // save on DB
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      release();
    }

    // ... my code is keep going
```

This is a text counter API, we send requests with messages in body to this API and count up the number of characters of each message. Then finally save it on DB. So I have to use mutex library to handle concurrent requests. If we make 100 requests at the same time and each of them has a message with a length of 10, total character count on DB should be 1000(100reqs * 10characters).

I tried this but got the wrong result. Instead of the expected result of 1000, it's been always around 450.

When looking console, it seems that the mutex object is instantiated several times. I thought this mutex object must be a singleton, initialised only once when a server is started and used for the rest of the process. I now know this new keyword creates an object on memory like Java, so this behaviour sounds strange.

Why Node.js does not use an already created mutex object and create another one? Is there some logic in Node.js creating new instance automatically when massive concurrent requests come?

Comment: JavaScript (what you use in Node.js) and Java are two different, separate languages. The `new` keyword in both languages happens to do the same thing (create a new object), but in general you shouldn't assume that the same keyword in different languages has exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword in Javascript (Node.js is runtime environment for Javascript, think Node.js is for Javascript as JRE is for Java) is paired with the `class` keyword.

These were introduced to add some familiarity for developers coming from other languages. The `class` syntax was introduced in ES6 and is just another way to create an object, most things in Javascript are objects.

Inside a `class` definition, a developer will write something like this:

```
    class MyClass {
        constructor(opts) {
            doSomethingWithOpts(opts);
            this.opts = opts;
        }

        myMethod() {
          // do something here
        }
    }
```

When you call `const myClass = new MyClass(opts);` it is calling the constructor function inside the class and returning a new copy of the class (which is an object). Prior to the ES6 `class` keyword, it was common to create new objects (which can be thought of in a similar fashion to a class) using something like this (called a factory):

```
const newObject = (opts) => {
  doSomethingWithOpts(opts);
  return {
    opts,
    myMethod() {
      // do something here
    },
  };
};
```

This factory would be called in your code like so: `const myObject = newObject(opts);` - notice the distinct lack of the new keyword in this version

Both variations of creating an object will add the object to memory stack, but once you are finished with it, the garbage collector will clean it up (provided the conditions for garbage collection are met).

Hopefully that helps clarify a little!

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I didn't know that normal javascript object in your second example is also on the memory. By the way, as I updated my post, is there any possibility that Node.js create the copy of an object that should be singleton object when tons of concurrent requests come? If you know something, could you share that knowledge?(I know this question is irrelevant to this original post, but if I couldn't solve this problem my boss would kill me. I'm dying to know the cause or how Node.js behaves in massive concurrent requests coming situation)

Comment: It depends on how you are running your Express server (nodemon/node/PM2) and where. The way you are importing/requiring files plays into it too. Its also quite possible your transactions/mutex aren't being handled correctly, which seems more likely to me. If you slow down you requests to one at a time, do you get the same problem?

Comment: No, when slowing down the rate of requests(sending requests not in a concurrent way), this problem never occur.

Comment: What are you storing this into? MySQL or something else? Looking at the code I’m imagining the mutex creation/handling isn’t being properly. 

When many requests come through, node.js will try and spin up more threads to handle those requests, which is why you’re getting this issue when sending heavy loads.

Comment: I've searched about node.js thread after reading your post, but couldn't gave me any clear idea to solve this... Now it seems better to me to look for another solution. Thank you very much for your response! Really appreciate it.